# When does netpoll() been called in Golang

Tags: go, epoll

Hi there， Im new Goer and confused by the netpoll() function.
Heres the thing. When I start a Httpserver like this

`http.ListenAndServe("127.0.0.1:9988",nil)`

as far as I concerned, there should be a gorouting or thread or something else do the epoll things to check the socket events.  Cause Im testing on MAC, the related runtime code is in "netpoll_kqueue.go". This func is called   by the sysmon().  In order to debug, I add some "println" to print out the related information.

The println is in
netpoll_kqueue.go:

```
func netpoll(block bool) *g {
if kq == -1 {
    return nil
}
var tp *timespec
var ts timespec
if !block {
    tp = &ts
}
var events [64]keventt
retry:
n := kevent(kq, nil, 0, &events[0], int32(len(events)), tp)
println("===============")
if n < 0 {
    if n != -_EINTR {
        println("runtime: kevent on fd", kq, "failed with", -n)
        throw("runtime: netpoll failed")
    }
    goto retry
}
```

and

```
proc.go.sysmon()

    asmcgocall(*cgo_yield, nil)
    }
    // poll network if not polled for more than 10ms
    lastpoll := int64(atomic.Load64(&sched.lastpoll))
    now := nanotime()
    println("+++++++++++++++++++++")
    if netpollinited() && lastpoll != 0 && lastpoll+10*1000*1000 < now {
        atomic.Cas64(&sched.lastpoll, uint64(lastpoll), uint64(now))
        gp := netpoll(false) // non-blocking - returns list of goroutines
        if gp != nil {
            // Need to decrement number of idle locked M's
            // (pretending that one more is running) before i
```

As mentioned before, as far as I concerned, the netpoll() function should been called frequently.  However, both "======" and "++++++" are printed only once. And, only when I send a request, the "======" and "++++" are printed.   It confused me a lot, according to the scenario, if the netpoll() is not the function to call system epoll and sysmon() is not the function to raise netpoll() then who do the job?

Appreciate your help

Comment: [The netpoll function is called in blocking mode](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/d278f09333edec3db982d1e4b4dfad0e1e8cce49/src/runtime/proc.go#L2469) in some circumstances.  The print statements will only be called once in this mode.

Comment: When you make a statement like "as far as I concerned, the netpoll() function should been called frequently. " you need to further explain _why_ you think that, because it obviously doesn't need to be called frequently since networking in Go does work correctly.